# Sybase - How to get logsegments off my data devices?

Tags: sybase

I'm running Sybase ASE 15.7 and coming up to speed to clean up a database server installed by a non-DBA.

I have a database that has the following device configuration:
[image: Sybase database device listing]

I want to have data1 and tlogs1 devices hosting only Data and Log respectively so that I don't encounter any anomalies in the event of a database restore due to a device failure.

How can I correct this configuration?

Note: The remove button is always grayed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to fix the database in place, but I did manage to solve this misconfiguration by:

- Creating a new database with my optimal device layout
- Migrating the schema via DDL generation scripts using `ddlgen.bat`
- Using `bcp` to migrate the table data

Note: You could use Sybase Central's DDL generator, but it doesn't include table's indexes for some reason.

When done, I have well documented database schema scripts to place in source control.

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to solve this is, as I think you discovered, is to create a new database (or drop and re-create the existing database). You don't need to do anything with DDL or `bcp` though.

When you run `DUMP DATABASE` the output is exactly as it would be inside the database. Looking at the output of `sp_helpdb` and `sp_helpdevice` should give you a rough idea of how the database is structured. The `sysusages` table in the `master` database is the best place to look at the database structure:

```
select * from master..sysusages where dbid=db_id(mydb) order by lstart
```

The `segmap` column specifies whether the segment is data, log or data+log.

Once you've examined the output of all of these, you can re-create the database with the correct segmaps:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb ON
data1=80
LOG ON
tlogs1=20,
tlogs1=20
```

If your database had been structured as a mix of something like data, log, log, data, log (i.e. it had been expanded several times with `ALTER DATABASE`) then you could use `bcp` to copy out all tables and re-create the database in a contigous order.